# How to set "search_type" in elasticsearch-js?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

After looking at this question: [ElasticSearch default scoring mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522272/elasticsearch-default-scoring-mechanism), I would like to use "dfs_query_then_fetch" rather than the default "query_then_fetch" search type. However, I am using elasticsearch-js client, and I can't figure out how to specify this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference-1-4.html#api-search-1-4) you should be able to achieve this by specifying the
***searchType*** option.

Comment: But is this in the query JSON itself or when you create a new Elasticsearch instance? I realize it's in the documentation but I find it a little vague for new users :)

Comment: @kairavichahal this is a part of the query JSON

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31814188/how-to-use-search-type-from-elasticsearch-javascript-library) for an example