# How to use search_type from elasticsearch javascript library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, npm

I am trying to execute a search query with `search_type` of `count` with the elasticsearch.angular.js build from [the npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch).

I can execute the query like this:

> POST /index1/type1/_search?search_type=count

```
 {
   "aggs": {
   "reviews": {
     "nested": {
       "path": "reviews"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but when I try to translate the query to the .js api, I get an error. My code looks like this:

```
  var requestObject = {
      index:'index1',
      type:'type1',
      searchType: 'count',
      body: {
        query:{
          aggs: {
            reviews: {
              nested: {
                path: "reviews"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    };
    esClient.search(requestObject)
```

The trace looks like this:

```
  console.js:1 DEBUG: 2015-08-04T15:28:59Z
      starting request { method: 'POST',
        path: '/index1/type1/_search',
        body: { aggs: { reviews: [Object] } },
        query: { search_type: 'count' } }
```

That looks OK to an elasticsearch newbie, but the request completes with an error: `ReferenceError: count is not defined`.

What am I missing here please?

Comment: It's probably not related (never know though), but the `aggs` part needs to be a direct child of the `body` element, i.e. not nested inside the `query` element. Can you make that change and try again to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's a JS error and not an ES error. Can you post how you're handing the response of `esClient.search()`?

Comment: @robertkliep I'm not at my computer now, but I am handling the response with the promise syntax.

Comment: @robertklep: just checked my response-handling code and sure enough I was console.logging something called 'count'. I'll blame it on the end of a long day, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my problem was a stupid error on my part (thanks @robertklep for pointing it out). The code above actually works correctly. As I was not able to find an example of using using `searchType` from the api, I am leaving this here in the hope it will be useful to somebody else.